# Improve Text Usability/Readability by changing the letter spacing and line height

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface

I would like to suggest a usability improvement for Stack Overflow.

When answers and comments are more than a few lines long, readability suffers from how close together the text appears. The lines and letters begin to blur together a bit, due to the small letter spacing and the line height being too tight. This is even more true for those with smaller screens and/or those who don't have 20/20 vision.

Additionally, line length is generally easier to read when the characters are somewhere around 45 to 75 characters long. Currently, character line length on Stack Overflow is around 90-95

I would like to suggest modifying the CSS for the `<p>` tags in answers/comments so that:

- Line height is increased to somewhere between 1.4em to 1.6em.
- Letter spacing is increased to around 0.01em.
- Possibly increase the font size to 15px or 16px so that the character line count is closer to 75 characters long.

Of course, I realize that though there is a lot of study done on readability, there's also a good deal of opinion and personal preference. Please feel free to submit your own CSS modification suggestions.

Thanks for considering.

Comment: comparison for [1.5em, 0.01em, 15px](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zPMEv.png) - just noticed you said "for comments/answers" but if you're changing answers I don't see why you wouldn't change questions. I though I was going to disagree with you, but I kinda like it.

Comment: +1 Nice suggestion, as OGHaza said, you can consider including questions in this feature request too

Comment: I would rather we didn’t mess with letter spacing. That should be a carefully thought-out feature of every font. (Applying `0.01em` to this question decreases readability for me, because “i”s become twice as wide and utterly awkward.)

Comment: @false: Did you see the comparison OGHaza posted in the comment above?  Holy crap, that's nice.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I did; we aren’t using the same font. https://i.imgur.com/aHSdtUq.png – note before the i in “possibly” and after the n in ”increase”, before the a in “character”, inconsistent spacing before and after the word “font”, etc.. In other words, it looks bad, and kerning exists because type designers know how to space letters. The other changes I completely agree with.

Comment: @OGHaza You're correct. The size modification I gave was a suggestion for the Comments. I'd need to play around with the Question/Answer font a bit as it's line length (93-103) is even longer than the Suggestions' (90-95).

Comment: Just to be the contrarian here: isn't this something an individual user can choose to adjust with something like UserStyles? I do like the additional spacing, though...

Comment: @TiesonT. If it was simply a matter of style, then I would agree with you here. But what I am suggesting is better readability.